# Length of unit circle

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $\it{l} $ be [the length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) of the unit circumference $\{(x,y):||(x,y)||=1\}$ in an arbitrary norm $||\cdot||$ in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ How to prove or disprove the inequalities $\it{l} \ge 6,\, \it{l} \le 8$? I find $\it{l} =8 $ if $||(x,y)||:=|x|+|y|.$

Comment: How about multipliying norms for which the inequalities hold by positive scalars?

Comment: @ nombre: Thank you. The question has been edited.

Comment: Ok. So I assume the distance used to measure length of arcs is that induced by $\| \ \|$. In that case, I think the inequalities might be true, but I don't know how to prove them. I'll come back if I get an idea.

Comment: I think a down vote should be explained.

Comment: This downvote isn't mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both inequalities are true; they are due to Gołab (1932), see references in section 7.4 of [The geometry of Minkowski spaces I](http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2900) by Horst Martini, Konrad J Swanepoel, Gunter Weiss. Moreover, $8$ is attained only when the unit circle is a parallelogram, and 6 is attained only when it's a linear image of a regular hexagon. Two book references for these results are

- "Minkowski Geometry" by A. G. Thompson, page 113-114
- "Geometry of spheres in normed spaces" by J. J. Schäffer, pages 17-19

Since the complete proof takes a while, I'll only summarize the main steps here.

#### $l\ge 6$

Suppose that $C$ is the unit circle for some norm. Fix a point $p\in C$. Draw the   circle $\{x\colon \|x-p\|=1\}$; it will cross $C$ at some point $q$. The points $p,q,q-p, -p, -q, p-q$ are vertices of a hexagon inscribed in $C$, because each of them has a unit norm. Since every side of this hexagon has length $1$, the length of $C$ is at least $6$. (Recall that length is the supremum of lengths of inscribed polygonal curves.)

#### $l\le 8$

1. There exist two unit vectors $u,v$ such that the parallelogram with vertices $\pm u\pm v$ contains the unit disk (takes some work).
2. The aforementioned parallelogram has length $8$ (clear).
3. When one convex domain contains another, the smaller domain has smaller perimeter (easy to prove in Euclidean plane, takes more work in general normed planes).

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive and professional answer.